# Simplest way to replace part of array with other array? (patching binary data into file)

Tags: arrays, powershell, variable-assignment

To patch a block of binary data into a file with PS this is the best I've come up with (everything hardcoded for brevity):

```
$bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("FILE.DAT")
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++) {
    $bytes[73 + $i] = (0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xA7, 0x91, 0xAB, 0xD2)[$i]
}
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("FILE.DAT", $bytes)
```

It works, but isn't there a simpler way to do this kind of thing on an array, e.g. with just one operator or call without that `for` loop that replaces elements (here: bytes) one-at-a-time?

With all the high-level goodies in PowerShell I'd hope there'd be something like a version of the `-replace` op, or `memcpy()` in C, or the trick `$b = $a | foreach {$_}` to force by val instead of by ref array assignment, or maybe this (which fails):

```
$bytes[73..79] = 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xA7, 0x91, 0xAB, 0xD2  # "Array assignment ... failed because assignment to slices is not supported"
```

On a second note, I notice the `@()` array operator is often used in examples like these although not required. Is there an argument for that?

Comment: There are some situations where `@()` *is* required, for instance if you need to ensure that the result of a subexpression is an array, regardless of how many items are returned. See [`about_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06x742cw.aspx) method which:

> Copies all the elements of the current one-dimensional array to the specified one-dimensional array starting at the specified destination array index.

```
([byte[]](0xCD, 0xCD, 0xCD, 0xA7, 0x91, 0xAB, 0xD2)).CopyTo($bytes,73)
```